# encode url to Unicode in javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf

So I have this url that contains the word *españa* in a variable say:

```
var country = "españa";
```

using `encodeURIComponent(country)` returns the **UTF-8** version of the string *Espa%C3%B1a* .. however, the server (tested on chrome) expects the **unicode** version of the string *%20Espa%F1a* ..

Is there any way to get the latter value for that specific string?

Comment: "Unicode" is not an encoding, it's an overarching standard. Looks like your server is expecting *Latin-1* or some such specialised encoding instead of UTF-8?!

Comment: @deceze I dont have enough knowledge, but I referred to this document to come to my conclusions: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Comment: Then be told that the encoding you're looking for is Latin-1 or ISO-8859-1, not "Unicode".

Comment: hacky but escape("España") == "Espa%F1a" which codes to codepoints